# vhdl testbench for a card game?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to implement a testbench for a VHDL project that simulates a card game.

I need to calculate the odds of winning in the game where the card is drawn at the press of a button, from a counter that keeps counting constantly.

To introduce randomness, I need to send a pulse at random time intervals to the card drawing module. I was just wondering how to implement it.

I have no idea how to implement one, so I tried this.

```
tb: process
   VARIABLE seed1, seed2: positive;
   VARIABLE rand: real;
   VARIABLE int_rand: integer;
   variable time_var1, time_var2: time ;
   begin
       uniform(seed1, seed2,rand);
       int_rand := INTEGER(trunc(rand*4096.0));
       int_rand := to_integer((to_unsigned(int_rand, 14)) );
       time_var2 := (10 ms + (int_rand*1 us));
end process;
```

Then, I send the pulse using

```
key1 <= '1';
wait for time_var2;
key1 <= '0';
wait for 2ns;
and repeat...
```

I'm using ModelSim Starter.

Answer (score 0):

The `math_real.uniform` is a good place to start, and you can then create a
test bench process with a function that gives a random time at each call, for
example:

```
process is  -- Test bench process

  variable seed1 : natural := 1;  -- Random seed1 for rnd_time function
  variable seed2 : natural := 1;  -- Random seed2 --||--

  impure function rnd_time return time is  -- Random time at each call
    variable rnd_real : real;      -- In range [0.0 .. 1.0]
    variable rnd_pos  : positive;  -- In range [0 .. 20]
  begin
    math_real.uniform(seed1, seed2, rnd_real);  -- Random real [0.0 .. 1.0[
    rnd_pos := positive(rnd_real * 21.0);  -- Scaling to [0 .. 20] steps
    return 50 ns + 10 ns * rnd_pos;  -- Minimum and step values
  end function;

begin
  while TRUE loop
    rnd_sig <= '0';
    wait for rnd_time;
    rnd_sig <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
  end loop;
end process;
```

For more advanced random generation, you can look to [Open Source VHDL
Verification Methodology (OS-VVM)](http://osvvm.org/).